# TLS 1.2 connection using Client Certificate and secp512r1 fails

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession, tls1.2, mutual-authentication

I'm trying to implement mutual TLS connection. Here is the flow:

- I generate the csr request (using elliptic curve key, secp512r1)
- Send the signing request to the server and receive the public key certificate as a response
- I make p12 certificate using public key certificate received in step2 with my ECC secp512r1 private key. I save it as "ca.p12" file in Documents
- when I get `NSURLAuthenticationMethodClientCertificate` challenge I resolve it using the credentials from this certificate
- Get `Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200` "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made."

While checking the traffic between server and client it appears that it's a client side issue.

***Questions***:

1. Does iOS 9/10 support elliptic curve keys, secp512r1 in TLS handshake?
2. Is there anything critical I missed?

Any thoughts, suggestions are really appreciated. Thanks.

```
public func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Swift.Void) {

//server trust works fine
if (challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod == NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust) {
    if (self.shouldTrustProtectionSpace(space: challenge.protectionSpace)) {
        completionHandler(.useCredential, URLCredential(trust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!))
    }
}
//This one causes the issue
else if (challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod == NSURLAuthenticationMethodClientCertificate) {
    let identityAndTrust: IdentityAndTrust = self.extractIdentity()

    let urlCredential: URLCredential = URLCredential(
        identity: identityAndTrust.identityRef,
        certificates: identityAndTrust.certArray as? [AnyObject],
        persistence: URLCredential.Persistence.forSession)
        completionHandler(.useCredential, urlCredential)
    }
}

struct IdentityAndTrust {
    var identityRef: SecIdentity
    var trust: SecTrust
    var certArray: AnyObject
}

func extractIdentity() -> IdentityAndTrust {
    var identityAndTrust: IdentityAndTrust!
    var securityError: OSStatus = errSecSuccess

    var path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as String
    path = path + "/ca.p12"
    //let path: String = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("client", ofType: "p12")!
    let PKCS12Data = NSData(contentsOfFile:path)!
    let key: NSString = kSecImportExportPassphrase as NSString
    let options: NSDictionary = [key : "123"]
    //create variable for holding security information
    //var privateKeyRef: SecKeyRef? = nil

    var items: CFArray?

    securityError = SecPKCS12Import(PKCS12Data, options, &items)

    if securityError == errSecSuccess {
        let certItems: CFArray = items as CFArray!
        let certItemsArray: Array = certItems as Array
        let dict: AnyObject? = certItemsArray.first
        if let certEntry: Dictionary = dict as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {

            // grab the identity
            let identityPointer: AnyObject? = certEntry["identity"]
            let secIdentityRef: SecIdentity = identityPointer as! SecIdentity!
            print("\(identityPointer)  :::: \(secIdentityRef)")
            // grab the trust
            let trustPointer: AnyObject? = certEntry["trust"]
            let trustRef: SecTrust = trustPointer as! SecTrust
            print("\(trustPointer)  :::: \(trustRef)")

            // grab the certificate chain
            var certRef: SecCertificate?
            SecIdentityCopyCertificate(secIdentityRef, &certRef)
            let certArray: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

            let reader = DmailReader.sharedReader
            let caCertString = reader.getCACert()
            let cerData = X509Utility.der(fromData: caCertString)

            let convertedData = cerData as! CFData
            let caCert = SecCertificateCreateWithData(nil, convertedData)
            certArray.add(certRef as SecCertificate!)
            certArray.add(caCert!)

            identityAndTrust = IdentityAndTrust(identityRef: secIdentityRef, trust: trustRef, certArray:  certArray)
        }
    }
    return identityAndTrust
}
```

Comment: According to PKIX (the Web's PKI), all certificates in the chain should (must?) use `secp512r1`. In addition, the server must support `secp512r1`. To see if `secp512r1` is the issue, test things with `secp256k1`. Its the most common curve and provides the most interoperability in this area.

Comment: @jww Unfortunately I can't test with secp256 as the server only supports secp512r

Comment: Well, the problem is Apple's SecureTransport can be buggy. Apple is well known for its poor quality of software (cf., [goto fail](https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2014/02/24/anatomy-of-a-goto-fail-apples-ssl-bug-explained-plus-an-unofficial-patch/), [SSL_OP_SAFARI_ECDHE_ECDSA_BUG](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/SSL_OP_SAFARI_ECDHE_ECDSA_BUG), etc). I think you need to isolate client certs from the secp512r1 curve to discover which is the problem. Using secp256k1 would have tested client certs. Can you test client certs with `openssl s_client` or another tool?

Comment: @jww I did the following: 1. generated PKC#12 on iOS, saved it to my documents folder, copied to desktop mac and extracted public certificate and private key into pem. 2.Updated openSSL to 1.0.2k 3.Used s_client to check client authentication: openssl s_client -connect myhost.ae:27447 -cert publicCert.pem -key privateKey.pem -CAfile serverCA.crt -state -debug ...It makes the handshake properly ( Verify return code: 0 (ok) )

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the server responded to my csr request with the certificate chain: one client certificate and one intermediate. I only parsed the first one and apparently skipped the intermediate.

```
 /*identity only contains client cert. Certificates is the array of intermediate certificates (in my case its 1, can be more)*/
 NSURLCredential *credential = [[NSURLCredential alloc]initWithIdentity:identity
                                                           certificates:certificates
                                                            persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistencePermanent];
```

Then passing it in `urlSession:didReceiveChallenge:completionHandler:`

```
completionHandler(.useCredential, urlCredential)
```